# How to view contents of HTMLTextWriter?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, htmltextwriter

I have an HtmlTextWriter object (theWriter) being passed into a method.  This method is in the middle tier.  I'd like to read the contents of the theWriter in debug mode.  The method is:

```
protected override void Render (HtmlTextWriter theWriter) {...}
```

which inherits from Panel:WebControl.

I've tried

```
theWriter.Flush();
theWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
```

but that only outputs the object type: "System.Web.HttpWriter".  I've seen some examples use methods on the Response object.  But I don't have access to Response in this layer.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InnerWriter` is a `TextWriter`-derived class, which writes to a stream. You will have to open that stream and read data from it. Whether you can open and read from that stream is an open question, and depends very much on what type of stream it is.

So to use your example, `theWriter.InnerWriter` is an object derived from `TextWriter`. But you don't know what kind, and `TextWriter` itself doesn't expose the underlying stream.

Now, if `InnerWriter` is a `StreamWriter`, then you might be able to write:

```
var sWriter = theWriter.InnerWriter as StreamWriter;
var stream = sWriter.BaseStream;
var savePosition = stream.Position;
stream.Position = 0;
// now, you can read the stream
// when you're done reading the stream, be sure to reset its position
stream.Position = savePosition;
```

You have to be very careful, though. If you get the base stream and then open it with a `StreamReader`, closing the `StreamReader`will close the underlying stream. Then your `HtmlTextWriter` will throw an exception the next time you try to write to it.

It's also possible that you won't be able to read the stream. If the base stream is a `NetworkStream`, for example, you can't read it. Or it could be a `FileStream` that was open for write only. There's no good general way to do this, as it entirely depends not only on the specific `TextWriter`-derived class, but also on the stream that the `TextWriter` is writing to.

For example, the `HtmlTextWriter` could be writing to a `StreamWriter`, which is connected to a `BufferedStream` connected to a `GZipStream`, which finally writes to a `MemoryStream`.

So, in general, I'd recommend that you look for some other solution to your problem. Unless you know for sure what the underlying stream is, and that you can read it ... and that things won't change on you unexpectedly.

Comment: additionally if you read the stream (in debug mode) you may have to reset the stream position so it can be used later in the program (even reading it in debug mode acts just as if you read it IRL (thats in real life))

Comment: Can you give an example of how this can be opened and read in debug mode?